# Gcloud: ubuntu xenia - port is not open

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, port, google-compute-engine

I had followed "google" whatever I can but still couldn't get through the port.

Basically I want to open port 8080, below command line is showing **"8080/tcp closed http-proxy"**, I already enable the firewall with 8080 and gcloud network firwall rules, but still failed.

and here what I did:

**CLI port open usw**

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
3389                       ALLOW       Anywhere
8080/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3389 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

nmap <external ip>

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-02-02 17:52 UTC
Nmap scan report for <external ip>.bc.googleusercontent.com (<external ip>)
Host is up (0.00097s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
8080/tcp closed http-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.87 seconds
```

**gcloud firewall rules**
[gcloud firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmV3C.png)

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved as mess up private IP and public IP, case closed, thanks